# Why does using UART2 on Tiva C result in a hard fault?

Tags: embedded, uart

I'm learning about the UART communication on the Tiva C Launchpad.  Everything was going fine until I tried to switch from UART5 to UART2. The first thing I noticed was that one of the UART2 Rx and Tx pins is a special pin that is protected by the commit register. As far as I know, setting its bit (the seventh, in this case) is enough, but I don't know. The code is not working and a hard fault arises whenever I try to run it. Here is the code.

```
#include <TM4C123GH6PM.h>

int main() {
  
  SYSCTL->RCGCUART |= 0x1 << 2;     //enable UART2 module clock
  //UART Config
  //Pins: U2Rx -> PD6
  //      U2Tx -> PD7
  UART2->CTL = 0;
  UART2->LCRH = 0x60;
  //9600 Baud Rate
  UART2->IBRD = 104;
  UART2->FBRD = 11;
  UART2->CC = 0;
  UART2->CTL = 0x301;
  
  SYSCTL->RCGCGPIO |= 0x1 << 3;     //Enable PORTD clock
  GPIOD->LOCK = 0x4C4F434B;
  GPIOD->CR = 0xFF;         //Enable PD7 to be used as a UART pin
  GPIOD->LOCK = 0;
  GPIOD->AFSEL = 0xC0;
  GPIOD->DEN = 0xC0;
  GPIOD->AMSEL = 0;
  GPIOD->PCTL = 0x11000000;
  
  
  while(1)
  {
    while((UART2->FR & 0x20) != 0);
      UART2->DR = 'X';
  }
  
}
```

I want to mention that this code (with minimal changes that is related to pins) works fine for UART5, I don't know why it doesn't work for UART2.

Comment: Do you have a debugger? Check to see if the power and clock are enabled on uart2

Comment: @Kartman I've used the debugger and the uart2, gpiod clocks are both enabled

Comment: can you access uart2 registers through the debugger? Where does it hard fault in the code? It it hards when you try to access uart2 registers, this suggests power and/or clock is not enabled.

Comment: @Kartman It faults in a weird fashion, when i run the code line by line in the debugger, nothing happens, no faults but the code still don't work. When i run it in one go or without the debugger it faults. I can't exactly tell where it faults because when i step through the code, nothing happens

Comment: you can use the debugger to examine memory and peripherals. Have you tried this? When it faults, have you decoded the stack to find out what caused the fault? Some debuggers will decode this for you, otherwise do some research and find the technique for decoding the stack anfter an exception. Standard ARM stuff.

Comment: have you tried enabling the gpio before the uart?

Comment: @Kartman Your comment was inspiring that I've fixed the hard fault problem but the code still not working. But at least, It doesn't hard fault. I should add some delay after enabling the peripheral clocks to give it a chance to get activated before the mcu gets to execute the instructions the access them.